# Lost log of calls after update iOS 16.1.1

Tags: iphone, ios, call

My iPhone 8 did an automatic software update to iOS 16.1.1. Suddenly I no longer find any calls in either the "all" or "missed" call log. Does anyone know what has happened?

Comment: Did you try recovery from your last backup?

Comment: Backup? It's a phone. I don't keep anything essential on it, so I don't back it up. Actually, I'm not sure how I would back it up. There is probably some app. Apple pushes the update anyway. I just wondered if this is a common occurrence, or some bug in the new iOS. I always delete the log anyway, so it is no inconvenience.